# Internet from Direct Broadcast Serivce

Tags: bandwidth

Internet is very much costly in India , like 3-5 USD  per GB @ 3G networks and even in broadband 100 USD for a unlimited banwith for 2 MBps but here DTH (Direct-To-Home broadcast service ) is very common and cheap , like 4$ for a month with most of the channels . I think to buffer a 480p video we would need 200 KB/s (2MBps ) plan in internet but how DTH providers give that much bandwidth for TV service for such a low price .

My main point here is :

1. Can we use DTH service for Internet using (direct from satellite like the DTH works).
2. Can we get same bandwidth for using internet just at same price just in case of DTH .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, because the internet depends on you having a method of sending data. For example, the question you've asked here came here somehow, so it's obvious you need to be able to *send* data.

Now, TV is *broadcasting*, it's a one-way transmission, without a back channel.

There are satellite internet access services, but they are far more costly than what you've described, and much much slower.

Also, some countries had things that used a telephone line as uplink and a sattelite downlink, but they suffered from cost, the asymmetry between the fast satellite downlink and the slow telephone uplink, and the poor latency.

Comment: thanks for the information bro . i have 2 things to ask . 
1) The DTH is a interactive service , here i can buy Movie on Demand and play games means it need to send some data .
2) Its okay for me to have a telephone line as uplink with a slow speed cause may be 10-20% uplink normally used compared to downlink but what do you meant by "suffered from cost " ?

If you know any companies that provide the same service as u described in last point (downlink via satellite and uplink with cellular ) please tell me ...

Comment: "suffered from cost" means that they practically disappeared from the market as DSL prices sank, and they lost their ability to compete. "Direct-to-home" usually refers to a way the satellite broadcast is sent to the satellite, so this is something that's more of a brand name than a technical description, as it seems. Sorry for the confusion!

Anyway, if your DTH provider offers you that uplink, he might as well be selling you internet. My wild guess is that this uplink is really thin, and you won't have much fun using that.

Comment: by the way "3-5 $ per GB" is really cheap compared to most German 3G/4G contracts, and far cheaper than what was available as hybrid Satellite/telephone access back in the early 2000s, if I remember correctly.